# How to set one column with two different scale for DECIMAL in SQL

Tags: sql

I have a pyspark dataframe that I've transformed similar to the one below:

| Category | Price |
| --- | --- |
| Fruit | 2.345 |
| Vege | 2.32451 |
| Junk | 34.23491 |
| Fruit | 2.390 |

The `Price` column should only have 3 decimals for fruit and any other category to have 5 decimals.

In order to get this data transformation, I used `DecimalType` then cast the values as strings. Currently, the datatype is set as `Decimal(20,5)` in SQL and when I try to insert the table into SQL it ends up converting the fruit price from 3 to 5 decimals.

I don't want to store the values as `NVARCHAR` in SQL because I want to be able run calculation queries in SQL.

What datatype should I set in my schema so that the number stays in the exact format in my pyspark dataframe without SQL adding extra 0's at the end of the fruit price?

Comment: database will always contain trailing zeroes because of data type. scaling is more for presentation therefore do it in the UI

Comment: Unlike the decimal floating-point types in most programming languages, SQL's `DECIMAL` has a fixed precision for all rows, there's no way around that. If you absolutely must retain the information about the scale, you could store this separately, although it makes retrieving the value more complicated. If it's the same per category, you can simply use that without storing it in the row and convert on retrieval (convert to `Decimal` and use `Decimal.quantize`, e.g. `Decimal('2.39000').quantize(Decimal('.000'))`).